# mysql query clarification

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query which I am wondering if the result I am getting is the one that I am expecting.

The table structure goes like this :

```
Table :  results     
ID TestCase Set  Analyzed Verdict StartTime             Platform
1  1010101  ros2 false    fail    18/04/2010 20:23:44   P1
2  1010101  ros3 false    fail    19/04/2010 22:22:33   P1
3  1232323  ros2 true     pass    19/04/2010 22:22:33   P1
4  1232323  ros3 false    fail    29/04/2010 22:22:33   P2

Table : testcases
ID TestCase type
1  1010101  NOSNOS
2  1232323  N212NS
```

is there any way to display only the latest fails on each platform?

in the above case

Result shoud be :

```
 ID TestCase Set  Analyzed Verdict StartTime             Platform type 
 2  1010101  ros3 false    fail    19/04/2010 22:22:33   P1       NOSNOS 
 4  1232323  ros3 false    fail    29/04/2010 22:22:33   P2       N212NS
```

Answer (score 5):

This should give you the latest fails per platform. It relies on `id`s being sequential by time.

Replace the `*` by the columns you actually need.

```
Select *
From results r
Join testcases t On ( t.testCase = r.testCase )
Where r.id In (
    Select Max(id)
    From results
    Where verdict = 'fail'
    Group By platform
)
```

---

Alternatively you can use a `Left Join` to get only the rows with greatest `startTime` per `platform`:

```
Select *
From results r
Join testcases t On ( t.testCase = r.testCase )
Left Join results r2 On (     r2.platform = r.platform
                          And r2.verdict = r.verdict
                          And r2.startTime > r.startTime )
Where r.verdict = 'fail'
  And r2.id Is Null
```

Comment: You're assuming that ids are sequential by time, by the way.  What if they're not?

Comment: I wouldn't recomment using "where id in (subquery)" , for performance reasons.

Comment: ceteras: Performance will have to be tested, but I'd say that `IN (subquery)` should perform fine in that case.

Comment: @Paul: Of course you're right, this relies on `id` being sequential. I mention that in my answer now, and added an alternative solution respecting this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use `group by Testcase` and `order by ID desc limit 1` with your query

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, I'm not sure if it's going to be efficient:

```
select r.*, t.type
from
(
Select TestCase, max(StartTime) lastDate
From results
group by TestCase
)big
inner join results r on r.StartTime = big.lastDate and r.TestCase = big.TestCase
inner join testcases t on t.TestCase = r.TestCase
```

I' suggest you store the ID from testcases table in `TestCase` column on results table, instead of the 'TestCase'. Depending on the data type on this column, you might get a little better performance.